# VW multiclass classification

Tags: text-mining, multi-class

I am new to vw and trying to do a multiclass text classification with 18 classes.

1. features are unigram, bigram and trigrams.
2. Total features are around 1.4 million
3. Total training examples 35 million

This is how my training data looks like
`11 |UniGram 19334:0.250 1597:0.250 104:0.250 682:0.250 |BiGram 708757:1.000 966191:1.000 |TriGram
11 |UniGram 1878:0.500 17678:0.500 |BiGram |TriGram
11 |UniGram 341:1.000 |BiGram |TriGram
11 |UniGram 275:0.250 287:0.250 479:0.250 249:0.250 |BiGram 709552:1.000 1017093:1.000 |TriGram
11 |UniGram 6981:0.500 985:0.500 |BiGram |TriGram
11 |UniGram 860:0.167 6253:0.167 24:0.167 571:0.167 163227:0.167 |BiGram 1082564:0.667 1006767:0.667 949487:0.667 |TriGram
11 |UniGram 870:0.250 13824:0.250 82:0.250 208:0.250 |BiGram |TriGram
11 |UniGram 3925:0.500 390:0.500 |BiGram |TriGram
11 |UniGram 1704:0.500 1185:0.500 |BiGram |TriGram
11 |UniGram 2612:0.500 3004:0.500 |BiGram |TriGram
13 |UniGram 218720:0.500 231:0.500 |BiGram |TriGram
13 |UniGram 231:0.333 |BiGram |TriGram
13 |UniGram 231:0.500 |BiGram |TriGram
13 |UniGram 29169:0.333 3198:0.333 119436:0.333 |BiGram 741003:1.333 |TriGram
13 |UniGram 245835:0.250 231:0.250 |BiGram |TriGram
13 |UniGram 2184:0.333 231:0.333 27:0.333 |BiGram |TriGram
13 |UniGram 218320:0.333 231:0.333 8:0.333 |BiGram |TriGram
13 |UniGram 8:0.250 52746:0.250 231:0.250 130367:0.250 |BiGram 741369:1.000 |TriGram 1320863:2.250
13 |UniGram 130367:0.500 231:0.500 |BiGram |TriGram
13 |UniGram 3198:0.500 1036:0.500 |BiGram |TriGram`

I have some doubts regarding my training

I trained using

`vw.exe  --oaa 18  -b 28  -d vwTrainingData.vw --readable_model m.model.txt -f  m.vw`

- how do i interpret the output generated during training ?

`l_regressor = m.vw
Num weight bits = 28
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
using no cache
Reading datafile = vwTrainingData.vw
num sources = 1
average    since         example     example  current  current  current
loss       last          counter      weight    label  predict features
1.000000   1.000000          1      1.0         11        1        7
0.500000   0.000000          2      2.0         11       11        3
0.250000   0.000000          4      4.0         11       11        7
0.125000   0.000000          8      8.0         11       11        3
0.062500   0.000000         16     16.0         11       11       10
0.031250   0.000000         32     32.0         11       11        3
0.015625   0.000000         64     64.0         11       11        3
0.007812   0.000000        128    128.0         11       11        3
0.003906   0.000000        256    256.0         11       11        4
0.001953   0.000000        512    512.0         11       11        3
0.000977   0.000000       1024   1024.0         11       11        3
0.000488   0.000000       2048   2048.0         11       11        1
0.000244   0.000000       4096   4096.0         11       11        3
0.000122   0.000000       8192   8192.0         11       11        3
0.000061   0.000000      16384  16384.0         11       11        9
0.000031   0.000000      32768  32768.0         11       11        1
0.000015   0.000000      65536  65536.0         11       11        4
0.000008   0.000000     131072 131072.0         11       11        3
0.000004   0.000000     262144 262144.0         11       11        3
0.000002   0.000000     524288 524288.0         11       11        3
0.000001   0.000000    1048576 1048576.0         11       11        1
0.000000   0.000000    2097152 2097152.0         11       11        1
0.000000   0.000000    4194304 4194304.0         11       11        3
0.000003   0.000005    8388608 8388608.0          3        3        1
0.000004   0.000005   16777216 16777216.0         12       12        4
0.000005   0.000007   33554432 33554432.0          6        6        2
finished run
number of examples per pass = 35766253
passes used = 1
weighted example sum = 3.57663e+07
weighted label sum = 0
average loss = 5.78758e-06
best constant = 0
total feature number = 143645637`

2. When i read the readable model file i see

`Version 7.7.0
Min label:-1.000000
Max label:1.000000
bits:28
0 pairs:
0 triples:
rank:0
lda:0
0 ngram:
0 skip:
options: --oaa 18`

- Why the min label and max labels are -1 and 1 ?
- Is there something that i am missing ?
- When i predict it always predicts one class. I feel that i am doing something completely wrong not sure what.

Comment: I can't answer you question, but note that running [this vw example](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/One-Against-All-%28oaa%29-multi-class-example) also results in min max labels being -1 and 1.

Comment: Regarding question 3 is i normal that you do "one against all" when you have multiple labels. Naive Bayes can deal with this.